# Spark on EMR Yarn - EOF Error

Tags: apache-spark, runtime-error, eof, pyspark, emr

We are running some PySpark processes on Yarn, when the datasets increase in size we are getting this error in the yarn log:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/daemon.py", line 157, in manager
      File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/daemon.py", line 61, in worker
      File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 136, in main
        if read_int(infile) == SpecialLengths.END_OF_STREAM:
      File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 544, in read_int
        raise EOFError
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at java.net.Socket.shutdownOutput(Socket.java:1496)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply$mcV$sp(PythonRDD.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(PythonRDD.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(PythonRDD.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLog(Utils.scala:1785)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1772)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:208)
```

We are running on a EMR Setup 3*m3.xlarge - each with 4vCPUs, 15GiB and 2x40 GB

The job is executed with the following sh script:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/home/hadoop/spark
JARS="/home/hadoop/avro-1.7.7.jar,/home/hadoop/spark-avro-master/target/scala-2.10/spark-avro_2.10-1.0.0.jar”

$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --py-files deploy.zip --jars $JARS main.py
```

where deploy.zip contains some utility methods and lambda functions

No other configuration changes were made to the cluster.

By looking at the UI seems that the all the jobs are finishing with a SUCCESS status, nevertheless we would like to get rid of this issue, or at the very least to understand what's causing it.

Would you have any idea on what it might be the origin of the error?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your executor memory, count and core settings?

Comment: these are our current settings:
--num-executors 2 
--executor-cores 4 
--executor-memory 4736m 
--driver-memory 5g